# Desktop is crashing when I try to use any app -Ubuntu 20.04 VM running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, gui, login-screen, crash

I hope you could help me to diagnose this problem. My environment is:

Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Release: 20.04 - Codename: focal

Oracle VirtualBox: Versión 6.1.8

When I search for an App, or click on one, or practically any interaction with the graphic interface, the desktop crashes, background turns black, window gets smaller, and then the login screen appears.  Any App that was open before the crash, is closed after it.  Last time I used this VM (like one month ago) everything was fine.

There is another problem I discovered today (I know I have to open another thread for a different problem, but I will only mention this here in case is related to the graphics problem):  **$ sudo apt-get update** is not working because of "Hash Sum mismatch" errors.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you,

Yonny

Comment: I have some clones of my VM, created at different times and statuses, I tried some of them today and got the same problem.  There are also new errors about  "Read only file systems".  I guess something went wrong with VirtualBox or Windows, because I even tried with a debian linux, and the same GUI error happened with that one too.  I don't know what happened with my system.  I tried to create a new VM, downloaded the .iso file, but could not, the installer did not recognize my keyboard, and some attempts failed with "ubiquity" errors.  Well, I give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ran into the same issue and I ran into multiple different errors.  By chance do you have WSL1/2 installed?  This seems to be the root issue of installation errors as well at apt errors for me.

For reference I am running VirtualBox 6.1.12 and Windows 10 Build 19041.421

The errors I received were:

- Errno 5: Input/output error
- System hangs/crashes on install
- Ubiquity errors (Even after disabling/upgrading)

Simply disabling WSL from the command line doesn't do what you want.  You'll have to go into `Windows Features` , disable it, reboot, and then you'll be able to access/install Ubuntu.

[Here is the setting you must disable in `Windows Features`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W08xz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this too. It started happening after enabling WSL. After disabling WSL as confusedandamused suggested, I also had to disable Virtual Machine Platform in Windows Features.

[image: Disable Virtual Machine Platform]

Seems like Virtual Machine Platform uses resources that VirtualBox needs, then VirtualBox crashes when they are not available.

If you need both VirtualBox and WSL, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031941/how-to-get-oracle-vm-virtualbox-6-0-and-wsl-working-at-the-same-time